# What Python Module extracts certain chars from raw input?

Tags: python, string

What Python module can I use to extract certain chars from raw input?
Example: user types in "1J1J"... I want Python to extract both the "J"s.

Comment: Can you provide me an example?

Comment: What do you want to do with the two JJs?

Comment: Thanks SilentGhost... I'll look elsewhere for an answer.

Comment: @SilentGhost let's remain polite... You don't have to answer if you don't like the question. Asking the poster to rephrase or be more precise might be a better idea.

Comment: @Benjamin: let's start being polite by not telling each other what to do.

Comment: @SilentGhost You told the OP what to do...

Comment: @FogleBird: you'd do too, if you had time to observe his antics

Comment: Tut tut.  Python devs are so cantankerous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

result = raw_input("Enter some string: ")
print result.replace("J","")
```

Running this and giving input: `1J1J` prints out:

```
11
```

Which is `1J1J` but with the "J"s extracted

Comment: What is this supposed to mean?

Comment: The example doesn't mean anything... I'm applying it to a program I'm trying to write... thanks man!

Comment: Running that will extract the 'J's out of whatever raw input is provided.  If the raw input given is "1J1J" it will extract the J's and print out "11".